# IdentityServer4 - Calling API from IProfileService implementation

Tags: identityserver4, bearer-token

I'm working on an MVC web project which is using IdentityServer4 to authenticate users, the web app then uses an access token provided to a user by IdentityServer (authorization code flow) to call an API. The IdentityServer has been configured to use Azure AD as an external identity provider, which is the primary mechanism for users to login. That's all working great.

Once authenticated, I need to query the web app's database to determine:

- If the user account is authorised to login
- Retrieve claims about the user specific to the application

The IdentityServer docs (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html) suggest implementing the IProfileService interface for this, which I've done. I want the ProfileService to call the web app's API to retrieve the information about the user to avoid forcing the IdentityServer to need to know about/directly access the database. My problem however, is that calling the API though needs an access token.

Is it possible to retrieve the token for the current user inside the ProfileService's IsActiveAsync / GetProfileDataAsync methods? I can't find solid documentation that identifies if the token is even generated at that point. I'm also a total noob when it comes to authentication/authorization, it's a massive topic!

I had the idea of using the client credentials flow inside the ProfileService to call the API, just to populate that initial token. However, I don't know whether or not that's an absolutely terrible idea... or if there are any better concepts someone could refer me to that I could investigate.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `ITokenCreationService` that is part of `identityserver4`. You can inject that service into your `IProfileService` implementation and then create a new bearer token with any claims you like.

For example:

```
protected readonly ITokenCreationService _tokenCreationService;

...

var token = new Token
{
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
    Issuer = "https://my.identityserver.com",
    Lifetime = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalSeconds,
    Claims = GetClaimsNeededForApiCall()
};

string myToken = await _tokenCreationService.CreateTokenAsync(token);

...
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible to retrieve the access_token for a user within ProfileService.
The profile service is called whenever IdentityServer needs to return claims about a user. This means if you try to generate a token for the user within ProfileService it will call the ProfileService again.

Comment: Thanks @nahidf, could you suggest any alternative approaches that would allow me to achieve what I've described, without forcing the IdentityServer to have excessive knowledge (or data access code) of the remote API? and do you have any feedback on mackie's answer which would seem to accomplish what I need.

Comment: You can call protected apis, but not the Api needs access_token issued for this user. I guess macki’s answer is to issue a user agnostic token as I see the code, you can try it and let me know what happened

Comment: At the end of the day a token is just a signed-over collection of claims. We've used the method in my answer to good effect in production. You'd just need to know in advance what claims the API you're calling needs.